# Jenkins not generating the full Karate.log

Tags: jenkins, karate

I am using the logback-test.xml from https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#logging . The karate log generated when the tests are executed locally has lot more information with the payload and response printed in the log. However, when we execute the same tests from jenkins, the karate.log is showing limited information. Please refer below logs for comparison.Is there any configuration required for showing the full information on Jenkins?

**Jenkins Execution: karate.log**

```
19:42:35.931 [Test worker] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - waiting for parallel features to complete ...
19:42:36.157 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
19:42:36.157 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
19:42:36.241 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Car Transaction Example
19:42:36.242 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Lodging Example
19:42:36.350 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<pass>> feature 3 of 3: classpath:products/example/test-cases/suite-b/us_lodging_creditcard.feature
19:42:36.350 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<pass>> feature 1 of 3: classpath:products/example/test-cases/suite-a/us_car.feature
```

**Local Execution: karate.log**

```
11:46:32.633 [Test worker] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - waiting for parallel features to complete ...
11:46:32.810 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
11:46:32.886 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Car Transaction Example
11:46:32.973 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<pass>> feature 1 of 2: classpath:products/example/test-cases/suite-a/us_car.feature
11:46:35.186 [Test worker] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - waiting for parallel features to complete ...
11:46:35.350 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
11:46:35.416 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] I am a happy happy test
11:46:35.499 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<pass>> feature 1 of 1: classpath:framework/example/test_framework.feature
11:46:36.994 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
11:46:36.996 [Test worker] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - waiting for parallel features to complete ...
11:46:37.148 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - backend sample-mock.feature initialized
11:46:37.149 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - all backends initialized
11:46:37.870 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - server started - http://127.0.0.1:9000
11:46:37.880 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - scenario called at line: 12 by tag: @addconsolerequest
11:46:37.956 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "consoleName": "PlayStation 5",
  "manufacturer": "Sony",
  "releaseDate": "09/12/2020",
  "price": 1150,
  "currency": "USD",
  "consoleInventoryCode": 21964477
}

11:46:38.383 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "serial_number": "7d241ad1-c048-48e2-9648-45add42d2b4e",
  "console_name": "PlayStation 5",
  "message": "A new game console has been added to the gamestore's inventory."
}

11:46:38.401 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - scenario called at line: 10 by tag: @addoperation
11:46:38.413 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] responseStatus: 201
11:46:38.420 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutting down
11:46:38.425 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutdown complete
11:46:38.430 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<pass>> feature 2 of 6: classpath:examples/sampleapp/tests/consoles/gamestore_api_console_tests.feature
11:46:38.457 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
11:46:38.494 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - backend sample-mock.feature initialized
11:46:38.494 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - all backends initialized
11:46:38.496 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - server started - http://127.0.0.1:9000
11:46:38.504 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - scenario called at line: 43 by tag: @addgamerequestps
11:46:38.550 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "gameTitle": "JUMANJI",
  "gamePlatform": "PlayStation",
  "compatibleWith": {
    "PlayStation5": true,
    "Playstation4": true
  },
  "releaseDate": "10/15/2021",
  "price": 45,
  "currency": "USD",
  "publisher": "Outright Games",
  "rating": "Teen",
  "gameInventoryCode": 545737836
}

11:46:38.606 [nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "confirmation_number": "45fd9c35-7d63-4e2e-9fc0-076b3bf7e94a",
  "gameTitle": "JUMANJI",
  "message": "A new game has been added to the playstation games inventory."
}

11:46:38.611 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutting down
11:46:38.613 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutdown complete
11:46:38.616 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<pass>> feature 5 of 6: classpath:examples/sampleapp/tests/games/gamestore_playstation_tests.feature
11:46:38.636 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
11:46:38.665 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - backend sample-mock.feature initialized
11:46:38.665 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - all backends initialized
11:46:38.667 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - server started - http://127.0.0.1:9000
11:46:38.674 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - scenario called at line: 19 by tag: @addgamerequestxbox
11:46:38.711 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "gameTitle": "FIFA 22",
  "gamePlatform": "Xbox",
  "compatibleWith": {
    "XboxOne": true,
    "XboxSeriesX": true,
    "Xbox360": false
  },
  "releaseDate": "10/1/2021",
  "price": 55,
  "currency": "USD",
  "publisher": "#(publsiher)",
  "gameInventoryCode": 1520969023
}

11:46:38.764 [nioEventLoopGroup-7-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "confirmation_number": "38a9d1cb-e899-43a2-8c8f-56f4bc43d0ab",
  "gameTitle": "FIFA 22",
  "message": "A new game has been added to the Xbox games inventory."
}

11:46:38.768 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutting down
11:46:38.771 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutdown complete
11:46:38.782 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
11:46:38.811 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - backend sample-mock.feature initialized
11:46:38.812 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - all backends initialized
11:46:38.813 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - server started - http://127.0.0.1:9000
11:46:38.841 [nioEventLoopGroup-9-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "game_id": "123",
  "gameTitle": "FIFA 2022",
  "releaseDate": "10/1/2021"
}

11:46:38.843 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutting down
11:46:38.846 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutdown complete
11:46:38.850 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: dev 
11:46:38.858 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - backend sample-mock.feature initialized
11:46:38.858 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - all backends initialized
11:46:38.860 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - server started - http://127.0.0.1:9000
11:46:38.881 [nioEventLoopGroup-11-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - no scenarios matched request
11:46:38.882 [nioEventLoopGroup-11-1] WARN  com.intuit.karate - no matching scenarios in backend feature files
11:46:38.884 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutting down
11:46:38.887 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3] INFO  c.intuit.karate.netty.FeatureServer - stop: shutdown complete
11:46:38.891 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - <<pass>> feature 6 of 6: classpath:examples/sampleapp/tests/games/gamestore_xbox_tests.feature
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with Karate, so please figure this out on your own if you cannot replicate the problem following these instructions: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue